# php strtotime "last friday April 2012" not returning last friday

Tags: php, strtotime

When I run the following code, I get the 30th of April rather than the 27th.

```
strtotime("Last Friday April 2012");
```

I tried running it as a Thursday instead and I got back the 29th.

All the following work fine.

```
strtotime("First Sunday February 2012");
strtotime("Third Monday February 2012");
strtotime("Second Monday October 2012");
strtotime("Fourth Thursday November 2012");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: strtotime is a wonderful example of garbage-in, garbage-out - your phrase is not specific enough, so strtotime guess wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are getting back the 30th of March, rather than of April, correct?

`Last Friday April 2012` does the following:

- `April 2012` sett the date to 2012-04-01
- `Last Friday` takes the date to the previous (last) Friday which is 2012-03-30

If you want the last Friday in April, use `Last Friday May 2012` instead,

See [Date/Time - Relative Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) from the PHP manual.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
strtotime("last friday of April 2012");

echo date( 'F jS, Y h:i:s A', strtotime("last friday of April 2012"));
```

This outputs the desired date:

```
April 27th, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```